# CSS Blur bleeding

Tags: html, css, frontend

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this: [subscription box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnMYG.png).

Should be trivial for experienced devs... problem is the gradient bleeds onto the white of the box, and doesn't end vertically, like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRQOA.png).

It's a simple box underneath the email form, with a gradient applied, and then blur (a lot of it). Ideally, the gradient rectangle's positioning should be anchored to the box.

Example of the code for the box and the gradient can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/YGbRYYnv)

```
pastebin^
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one helps you

```
box-shadow: 0px 30px 10px 0px #EBEBEB ;
```

Also, you can see more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)

Answer (score 0):

although the below answer is correct! You might only want one side to have the inner shadow as well as use the inset keyword to have the shadow inside the element

```css
.oneside{

   -moz-box-shadow:    inset  0 6px 6px -6px black;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset  0 6px 6px -6px black;
   box-shadow:         inset  0 6px 6px -6px black;
   border-radius: 4px;
  }

  .allaround{
          -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000000 ;
          -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000000 ;
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000000 ;
            border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <head>

        <body>
 <input class="oneside">
one side
</input>
</br>

<input class="allaround">
all around
</input>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry guys, but I don't think you understood. There is a gradient under the email form. This gradient is a rectangle with a gradient fill applied to it, blurred a lot, and is supposed to sit  under the form, at the background level. However, what happens is that  it bleeds through the white box, which then turns not white.